# BackboneJS connect modules with each other

Tags: backbone.js

I have a Backbone App where I have 2 modules. Now I have the issue that in module 1 there are some function and definitions which I also need in module 2.

so, in my module2.js I tried to do this:

```
define(['app', 'backbone','modules/module1'],

function (App, Backbone, Module1) {

Module2.View = Backbone.View.extend({
 afterRender:function(){
    var module1 = new Module1.View();
    ....
```

So again, I just want to add some functions I have defined in module1 to connect with module2, so that in module2 I can add some `if`-statements etc.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you showed what you tried (thanks) but didn't explain what's not working about it (is there an error in the console?)

Comment: @RobertLevy Ah sorry, no - there is no error in the console. Just nothing happens :-/

Comment: ok what would you expect to happen?  the code you posted doesnt actually do anything (though it would have an exception if it's executed without module1 being found)